# Could not find ti.millennialmedia for architecture : arm64

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, ios9.1

ti.millennialmedia module (for advertisements in iOS )has been used in Titanium app of Titanium SDK version 3.2.2 and it worked till Titanium SDK 3.4.0 also,but now I installed Appcelerator studio with Titanium SDK version 5.0.1,ti.millennialmedia module is displaying error of "Could not find timillennialmedia for architecture: arm 64".

I have gone through the Titanium documentation of converting 32 bit module into 64 bit architecture but I am unable to convert the module into 64 bit architecture and also  I am not getting any latest ti.millennialmedia module to integrate in my latest Appcelerator build app.Please someone help me in getting this module and pls tell of how to integrate in my appcelerator build app.

Comment: your post title asks about why the error is triggering, but in fact, you're actually asking someone to convert your module for you? This is totally off topic here. You could try and ask someone of the Titanium Community, they might want to help you out. Check http://www.tislack.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these steps if you have source code:

1. Open module project in Xcode.
2. Go to build settings of target.
3. Add architectures with arm64 and x86_64 alongwith standard architecture.
4. Now build the project.
5. Now open the project in finder and run build.py on Terminal.

   If everything runs fine you may have your zip for that module.
   And if build fails then the code on native side is not running for added architecture. So you need to modify your code.

Comment: Thanks..!!!  Krishna, converted the module with architecture  arm64, by following your steps....

Comment: Glad that it helped you.. You can accept it as answer so that it can help others..